# form validation as well as db error

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, validation

I'm getting an error on form validation as well as db error. When I remove form validation the db query works perfectly fine. I have no idea what the error is and how to solve it.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 953

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ` = 'admin' LIMIT 1' at line 2

SELECT * WHERE ` = 'admin' LIMIT 1

Filename: C:\wamp\www\myblog.com\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

[Controller: myblog]

```
class Myblog extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('blogmodel');

        }


    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('login');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
    public function login_check()
    {
        $user=$this->input->post("username");
        $pass=$this->input->post("password");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|is_unique');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
        if($this->form_validation->run()==true)
        {
            $this->blogmodel->checklogin($user,$pass);
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('logsuccess');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
        else
        {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('login');
        $this->load->view('footer');
        }
    }

    public function reg()
    {       
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|is_unique');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
        if($this->form_validation->run()==true)
        {   
            $user=$this->input->post("username");
            $pass=$this->input->post("password");
            $this->blogmodel->register($user,$pass);
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('regsuccess');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }

        else
            {
                redirect('myblog/login');           
   }
}





[Model: blogmodel]

class Blogmodel extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function checklogin($user,$pass)
    {
        $this->db->select('username, password');
        $this->db->from('user');
        $this->db->where('username', $user);
        $this->db->where('password', MD5($pass));
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() == 1) { 
            return $query->result(); 
        } else {
            redirect('myblog/login');
        }
    }

    function register($user,$pass)
    {
            $new_member=array(
            'username' => $user,
            'password' => md5($pass),
            'status' =>1
        );
        $insert = $this->db->insert('user', $new_member);
        return $insert;     
    }
```

[View:login]

```
   echo "<h2>Register</h2>";
   echo validation_errors();
   echo form_open('myblog/reg'); 
   echo form_label("Username: ");
   echo form_input("username");
   ?><br/>
   <?php
   echo form_label("Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;");
   echo form_password("password");
   ?><br/>
   <?php
   echo form_label("Confirm Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;");
   echo form_password("password2");
   ?><br/>
   <?php
   echo form_submit("","Register");
   echo form_close();


   echo "<h2>Login</h2>";
   echo validation_errors();
   echo form_open('myblog/login_check'); 
   echo form_label("Username: ");
   echo form_input("username");
   ?><br/>
   <?php
   echo form_label("Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;");
   echo form_password("password");
   ?><br/>
   <?php
   echo form_submit("","Login");
   echo form_close();
```

Comment: Your username form validation should have the table name in the is_unique rule. is_unique[users.username]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is because you haven't set a table or row in your form validation.

Change this line, in your Controller;

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|is_unique');
```

to this;

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|is_unique[users.username]');
```

As you'll see, I've added [users.username] to the is_inque rule. Without it, CI doesn't know what to compare it to.

Comment: I'm sorry, i dint get you. Im new to stckovrflw. How do I accept the answer??

Comment: On the left hand side of this answer, there will be a little tick. You click that on the answer you think is right. This makes it easier for anyone else who has this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Statement is missing the table and column to check

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 'admin' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: yes, when I remove the form validation, it works fine. I have specified table and all necessary fields on my model. But when I apply form validation, it shows this kind of db error.

Comment: Guess we need to see Form_validation.php and DB_driver.php to help some more

Comment: Those are not custom files, they are default files in CI. Could you please go through reg() func in myblog controller and register() fun in blogmodel. The problem seems to be there. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL syntax incorrect.
Your incomplete sql statement indicates that you want to fetch a COLUMN VALUE from a TABLE that contains the values of your Username.
So.include an appropriate Column name and  table name,
Syntax:

Select * from table_name where column_name='admin' Limit 1;